# my answer has been deleted along with its question by diamond moderator nbro

Tags: discussion, support, bug, moderators, moderation

###### Raising concern here as Flags and request for moderator intervention has failed. Requesting intervention of AI staff moderators.

It has come to my attention this question(https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/32012/educational-resources-and-programming-languages-for-ai-ml/32016#32016)  has been deleted by **diamond moderator [nbro](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2444/nbro)** without cause.

Kindly note this question was locked due to historical significance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your answer was deleted along with the question, which was too broad and partially off-topic. Questions that are off-topic and are of no value to our community can be deleted by moderators. Our community focuses the **theoretical aspects of artificial intelligence**. Asking for books, sources, programming languages, etc., all at the same time is too broad, which can lead to poor answers, so this is discouraged.

Please, read [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions), which states

> Questions that are **extremely off topic**, or of **very low quality**, may be removed at the discretion of the community and **moderators**.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from being off-topic, the "locked due historical significance" seems rather dubious and definitely does not satisfy the [reasons for locking a post in such a way listed here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts). As hanugm rightfully pointed out in a comment to that now-deleted question, we already have plenty of much older questions of a similar nature with much more activity on them. We're not losing anything major by deleting this, so the deletion is fine.

Comment: When a question is off-topic, it's closed as such. When it cannot be made on-topic (e.g. by editing without invalidating current answers) and has no historical significance, then, sometimes, I happened to lock it as obsolete, before eventually deleting the post. In this case, I locked the post as "historically significant", but that was the wrong lock. I wanted to close it as "obsolete", to avoid interactions and because this type of post can really become obsolete easily, apart from being too broad and leading to opinion-based answers.