# Answer deleted along with question diamond moderator nbro- III

Tags: discussion, support, bug, moderators, moderation

###### Raising concern here as Flags and request for moderator intervention has failed. Requesting intervention of AI staff moderators.

It has come to my attention this question has been deleted by **diamond moderator [nbro](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/2444/nbro)** without cause.

Why did diamond moderator misuse his powers to delete all my answers and associated questions?
**Nbro** kindly provide an explanation

**UPDATE** : This question closed as off topic 2 months ago, A just and unbaised moderator would have done the right thing and transfer to relevant SE site instead of deleting recently. **Was it some sort of personal vendetta against me?**

https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/32164/how-to-take-data-at-regular-intervals/32169#32169

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As [nbro already wrote](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2840/1641), this question was both off-topic and of extremely poor quality, so deletion is fine.

> This question closed as off topic 2 months ago, A just and unbaised moderator would have done the right thing and transfer to relevant SE site instead of deleting recently.

Probably the only valid target site to migrate towards would have been StackOverflow in this case. However, [generally we do not want to migrate poor-quality questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/376651), which this question was. It showed no effort at all, did not demonstrate what the author already attempted, it's basically a "please do my work for me" question. It would have been massively downvoted or even again deleted over on StackOverflow too.

Answer (score 2):

As written in [my other answer](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2837/2444), this question was deleted because it was **off-topic and unclear**, so **very poor**. Programming questions are off-topic here. Please, take a look at [our on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).